# How to get the status of massive controls created dynamicly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I am a greener in asp.net and trying to implement a use case which describes the process of user's choosing and booking a seat in Online Movie Booking System recently.

Now I have created massive seat controls, web user controls which is defined on the basis of the ImageButton, and a 'Submit' button.

These seat controls, seem to work well. The status of seats reflected by the picture within them can change as you clicked them. In the click event of 'Submit' button, I attempt to gather their states with their IDs but those states all are the same as those in the database, which means the status of these controls did not changed.

So, what should I do to get the current status of those controls when I click the 'Submit' button? Any idea would appreciate!

Seat.ascx

```
public partial class Seat : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    private string[] Images = { "~/picture/SeatStatus/Default.png", "~/picture/SeatStatus/Chosen.png", "~/picture/SeatStatus/Unavailable.png" };

    public string ImageLoc
    {

            get
            {
                return this.SeatControl.ImageUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                this.SeatControl.ImageUrl = value;
            }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
            if (ImageLoc == Images[0])
            {
                ImageLoc = Images[1];//switch to chosen state 
            }
            else if (ImageLoc == Images[1] )
            {
                ImageLoc = Images[0];  //switch to available state 
            }
            else
            {
                //Can not be chosen
            }
    }

}
```

ChooseSeat.aspx

```
 <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Table  ID="SeatTable" runat="server">
             </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<div>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" text="Submit" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" />
</div>
```

CreateControl

```
TableRow Row = new TableRow();
    Row.ID = "Row" + RowNum.ToString();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        TableCell Cell;
        //'0' represent available, '1' means the seat has been choosen , '2' //stands for unavailable
        if (str[i] == '0' || str[i] == '1' || str[i] == '2')
        {
            Cell = new TableCell();
            ColNum++;
            Cell.ID = "Row" + RowNum.ToString() + "Cell" + ColNum.ToString();

            Seat seat = (Seat)LoadControl("~/Seat.ascx");
            seat.ID = "Seat" + Cell.ID;
            seat.ID = string.Format("{0}", i);
            seat.ImageLoc = Images[str[i] - '0'];

            Cell.Controls.Add(seat);
            Row.Cells.Add(Cell);

        }
        else if (str[i] == '3')//3 means passageway
        {
            Cell = new TableCell();
            Cell.ID = "Label" + "Row" + RowNum.ToString() + "Cell" + ColNum.ToString();

            Label label = new Label();
            label.ID = "Ocup" + Cell.ID;

            Cell.Controls.Add(label);
            Row.Cells.Add(Cell);
        }
        else if (str[i] == '-')//'-' means next row
        {

            SeatTable.Rows.Add(Row);

            Row = new TableRow();
            RowNum++;
            Row.ID = "Row" + RowNum.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            SeatTable.Rows.Add(Row);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to post some code to show the issue - sounds like you are not posting back to the server when you change the state of a control

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I put those control into a UpdatePanel to avoid page flicking but I don know whether it would post back to the server when these control states changed or not.

Comment: I dont see any code to send your changed state to the database or get the state back -